# Detect window.open() from UIWebView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiwebview

Short question: Is it possible to detect `window.open()` in a `UIWebView` using the `UIWebViewDelegate` or is there another way to reach this? I need the the url when a `window.open()`-Event is fired to show a `UIAlertView`.

Comment: Hi Fabio, can you please elaborate how to use stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString in shouldStartLoadWithRequest to show UIAlertview. Thanks

Comment: With my code below you can overwrite `window.open` to work like a normal link. You're just able to detect if it's from `window.open` if you add a parameter like `?windowopen=true` and have a look for this URI in `shouldStartLoadingWithRequest:`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to overwrite `window.open()` using JavaScript:

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.open = function (open) { return function  (url, name, features) { window.location.href = url; return window; }; } (window.open);"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this delegate methods. Hope this helps.

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType;
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I was asking if the `UIWebViewDelegate` will detect `window.open()`. `target="_blank"` doesn't fire an event, that's why I ask.