# Open link in external browser

Tags: javascript, html, iphone, ios7, webview

I am working on one app that parses RSS feeds and show details in webview. I want to open links in external browser when clicked in webview, but one problem is hyperlink type it is as below:

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('http://test.com', '_system', 'location=yes');"><img src="xyz.png"></a>
```

Can you please tell me how to get event when this clicked in webview? Any help will be appreciated?

Comment: I have declared the delegate for webview but not getting any event. Please help me with this.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10909190/detect-window-open-from-uiwebview  That solution works as-is for opening the links in the web view.

Comment: @Brian Not working. Any other solution.

Comment: @BrianNickel Can you please tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can detect and intercept `window.open` calls by overriding the JavaScript function after the page loads:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.open = function(url) { window.location.href = 'open-' + url; return window; };"];
}
```

When someone taps that link, you will trigger a navigation to `open-http://test.com` which you can detect with your delegate and then launch Safari:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    if ([request.URL.scheme hasPrefix:@"open-"]) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[request.URL.absoluteString substringFromIndex:5]]];
        return NO;
    }

    // Other logic
    return YES;
}
```