# Detecting onclick on an ASP page on webView Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, webview, asp-classic, onclick

I am using `Classic ASP` for my server page. When the following URL is loaded on `webView`. I will detect the link when user click on the `webView` using `- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType`
If `classbook.asp` is detected when a new URL link is clicked on `the webView`, I will trigger a segue to load a new `VC` and load the new `webView`

However there is another google map link on the `webView` trigger by the following `Classic ASP onclick` code.

How do I detect when this google map link is clicked on the `webView`? Currently, the above method which is used to detect URL links cannot detect `onclick`

## Server Classic ASP

```
<div id="map" onclick="window.open('http://maps.google.com/maps?q=<%=sLat%>,<%=sLongi%>(<%=sFCName%>)', '_system');"></div>
```

## Objective C

```
@interface ClassesDet (){

    AppDelegate *appDelegate;
    NSString *sURL;
    NSString *sURLFav;
}
@end

@implementation ClassesDet

@synthesize webView;

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    sURL = @"https://www.share-fitness.com/apps/class_det.asp?classcode=CLS100032&access=C&memcode=SF100035&catcode=YG&fccode=KL00059&dtpclass=24/04/2018&tpfrom=20:15&fav=false&lang=EN&encode=20a728210f0869f04aab6cf1682881816a36f0bd47cc894ac4d8dd22dd0ded24" 

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:sURL];
    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webView setDelegate:(id<UIWebViewDelegate>)self];
    [webView loadRequest:urlRequest];


}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    ClassBook *target = segue.destinationViewController;

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"ClassBook"]) {

        NSLog(@" To ClassBook sURL : %@", sURL);
        target.urlString = sURL;

    } else {

        NSLog(@" Else to Other VC and the sURL : %@", sURL);
        target.urlString = sURL;
    }
 }

    - (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

    NSURL *URL = [request URL];
    NSString *theString = [URL absoluteString];
    NSRange match;

    NSLog(@"The URL Clicked : %@", sURL);

    match = [theString rangeOfString: @"classbook.asp"];

    //---If the URL string does not contain classbook.asp meaning it is loading the webview.
    if (match.location == NSNotFound) {

        NSLog(@"Load the webView with this sURL : %@", sURL);
        return YES; //---Load webview, the URL will be sURL nothing to do with theString

    } else {

        sURL = theString;

        NSLog(@"Trigger the Segue ClassBook and pass the sURL : %@  Over ",sURL );
        //---Calling the following method will trigger the segue and redirect to another viewController.
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ClassBook" sender:self];

        return NO; //---Don't load the webview
    }


}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11106153/422156) The problem you're having is that `shouldStartLoadWithRequest:` doesn't get called on JavaScript `window.open()`. The answer at the link has one way of making sure your code gets called. I was thinking one of the delegate methods would catch this but now I don't see it. Perhaps I was thinking of `WKWebView`.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    if ([webView.request.URL.absoluteString containsString:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?q"]) {
      //Your logic if require
    }
    else {
      //Your logic if require
    }
    return YES;
}
```